# New to Python, trying to build a web scraper

Tags: python, csv

Just downloaded Python 3.6 (yesterday) and looking forward to learning the language. For my first project, I'd like to build a web scraper. I've looked at a few examples online and settled on one. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import csv
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.showmeboone.com/sheriff/JailResidents/JailResidents.asp'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find('tbody', attrs={'class': 'stripe'})

list_of_rows = []
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
        text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')
        list_of_cells.append(text)
    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)

outfile = open("./inmates.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Last", "First", "Middle", "Gender", "Race", "Age", "City", "State"])
writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

When I attempt to run, however, I receive the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BeautifulSoup'
```

I went through and installed BeautifulSoup, but still nothing. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: How did you install BeautifulSoup? Does `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` work?

Comment: My bad.. it was towards the end.. so didnt read that you installed it already..

Comment: It says a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
import bs4
```

not

```
 import BeautifulSoup.
```

also, you may consider the following format:

```
import urllib.request
link = "some url"    

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read() #reads in the link
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(sauce,"lxml").get_text() #gets text from thr link
lines = soup.split("\n") #split by lines
```